# String replacement with .subst in a for loop

Tags: raku, string-substitution

I'd like to make a string substitution in a `for` block using a named capture. I've expected to get the numbers 1,2,3 as output. But it is `Nil` for the first run, and then 1 and 2 for the 2nd and 3rd run. How do I use the `.subst` correctly in the loop construct? I see the same behavior when using a `map` construct instead the `for` loop. It does work as expected, if I replace with a fixed string value.

```
for <a1 b2 c3> -> $var {
    say $var;
    say $var.subst(/.$<nr>=(\d)/, $<nr>); #.subst(/.$<nr>=(\d)/, 'X'); #OK      
}

#`[
This is Rakudo version 2019.11 built on MoarVM version 2019.11   
Output:

a1
Use of Nil in string context
  in block  at test3.pl6 line 3

b2
1
c3
2
]
```

Comment: I am curious. What is $<nr> ? (I couldn’t find it in the raku documentation.)

Comment: @p6steve [named capture](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Named_captures)

Comment: https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex__Named_captures-Named_captures - thanks @valle - found it now!

Comment: Perhaps consider using `S///` sometimes. In this case you could do `S[.$<nr>=(\d)] = $<nr> given $var`

Comment: @JoKing Nice. I upvoted your comment, then undid the upvote because I realized I wanted to check something (which turned out to not matter), and now SO won't let me reinstate my upvote. So I'm writing this to manually +1 your nice suggestion. I've also integrated it into my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** Defer evaluation of `$<nr>` until after evaluation of the regex. @JoKing++ suggests [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867250/string-replacement-with-subst-in-a-for-loop#comment106072405_59867250). Another is to just wrap the replacement with braces (`{$<nr>}`).

## What happens when your original code calls `subst`

Before Raku attempts to call the `subst` routine, it puts together a list of arguments to pass to it.

There are two values. The first is a regex. *It does **not** run*. The second value is `$<nr>`. It evaluates to `Nil` because, at the start of a program, the current match object variable is bound to something that claims its value is `Nil` and any attempt to access the value of a key within it -- `$<nr>` -- also returns `Nil`. So things have already gone wrong at this point, before `subst` ever runs.

Once Raku has assembled this list of arguments, it attempts to call `subst`. It succeeds, and `subst` runs.

To get the next match, `subst` runs the regex. This updates the current match object variable `$/`. But it's too late to make any difference to the substitution value that has already been passed to `subst`.

With match in hand, `subst` next looks at the substitution argument. It finds it's `Nil` and acts accordingly.

For the *second* call of `subst`, `$<nr>` has taken on the value from the *first* call of `subst`. And so on.

## Two ways to defer evaluation of `$<nr>`

@JoKing suggests considering use of `S///`. This construct evaluates the regex (between the first pair of `/`s) first, then the replacement (between the last pair of `/`s). (The same principle applies if you use other valid `S` syntaxes like `S[...] = ...`.)

If you use `subst`, then, as explained in the previous section, Raku puts together the argument list for it before calling it. It finds a regex (which it does not run) and a closure (which it does not run either). It then attempts to call `subst` with those arguments and succeeds in doing so.

Next, `subst` starts running. It has received code for both the *match* (a regex) and the *substitution* (a closure).

It runs the regex as the matching operation. If the regex returns a match then `subst` runs the closure and uses the value it returns as the substitution.

Thus, because we switched from passing `$<nr>` as a naked value, which meant it got frozen into `Nil`, to passing it wrapped in a closure, which deferred its evaluation until `$/` had been set to a match with a populated `<nr>` entry, we solved the problem.

Note that this only works because whoever designed/implemented `subst` was smart/nice enough to allow both the match *and* substitution arguments to be forms of `Code` (a regex for the match and ordinary closure for the substitution) if a user wants that. It then runs the *match* first and only *then* runs the substitution closure if it's been passed one, using the *result* of that latter call as the final substitution. Similarly, `S///` works because *that* has been designed to only evaluate the replacement after it's first evaluated the substitution.